# How can I connect to SQL through RODBC?

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I am trying to connect R to SQL to upload data and I do not manage to use the connection string. I have tried the following code:

I keep getting the error: "SQL Server does not exist or access denied."

```
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=local;database=db;trusted_connection=true')
```

I would like to ask you what could have gone wrong?

It is probably related to driver or server. Could you please tell me where exactly I can find these information?

Also, please notice I am using Windows Authentication.

Comment: what are the permissions on hte server? Should R have access? do you need to specify the `pwd` and `uid` arguments?

Comment: Related to what are the permissions I honestly don't know. All I would like to do is to upload data on SQL and then download them on R at convenience. I believe I do not need pwd and uid because I login with Windows authentication. Would you know how can I fix this issue with the server name? I also noticed that my server name is .\SQLEXPRESS and whenever R recognizes the combination "\S" it throws an error. Is maybe this the problem? If yes, how can I fix it? Many thanks in advance

Comment: R needs slashes to be / or \\. A single backslash will often cause errors

Comment: Thanks a lot, solved with your suggestion!